Replace Plank with classical Ubuntu dock in Budgie
I installed Budgie 24.02, but I don't like the Plank dock, and I wish to know if it is possible to use the classical Ubuntu dock.

What do you mean by classical Ubuntu dock? Do you mean the GNOME Dash to Dock extension?

Precisely, the dash-to-dock extension

The Ubuntu Dock is implemented as a Gnome Shell extension in the default Ubuntu desktop. Gnome Shell extensions can only be installed in a Gnome Shell desktop, hence not in Budgie or any other desktop.
So, no, this is not possible.
